# Python: cluster jobs management

Tags: python, cluster-computing, slurm

I am running python scripts on a computing cluster (slurm) with two stages and they are sequential. I wrote two python scripts, one for Stage 1 and another for Stage 2. Every morning I check if all Stage 1 jobs are completed visually. Only then, I start Stage 2.

Is there a more elegant/automated way by combining all stages and job management in a single python script? How can I tell if the job has completed?

The workflow is similar to the following:

```
while not job_list.all_complete():
    for job in job_list:
        if job.empty():
            job.submit_stage1()

        if job.complete_stage1():
            job.submit_stage2()

    sleep(60)
```

Comment: What is the output of these stages? How do you know when a stage is done?

Comment: I try to make it as general as possible. Is there any way to skip the "end file"?

Comment: I mean, you could have your jobs return a value when they're done. But that's hard in a distributed system.

Comment: I suppose it is also necessary to keep the python running in the background to moniter the jobs until all of them are done. So maybe the pseudo code is a good direction to go.
But what if the job went wrong? How could I indicate a rerun?

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890312/how-to-design-a-distributed-job-scheduler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several courses of action:

- use the [Slurm Python API](https://github.com/PySlurm/pyslurm) to manage the jobs
- use job dependencies (search for `--dependency` in the [sbatch man page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html))
- have the submission script for stage 1 submit the job for stage 2 when it finished
- use a workflow management system such as

  - Fireworks https://materialsproject.github.io/fireworks/
  - Bosco https://osg-bosco.github.io/docs/
  - Slurm pipelines https://github.com/acorg/slurm-pipeline
  - Luigi https://github.com/spotify/luigi

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a lot to go off of for how to determine if a job is finished, but a common way to solve this problem is to have the jobs create a sentinel file that you can look for, something like `COMPLETE`.

To do this you just add something like

```
# At the end of stage 1,
job_num = 1234
open('/shared/file/system/or/server/JOB_{job_num}/COMPLETE', 'x').close()
```

And then you just poll every once in a while to see if you have a `COMPLETE` file for all of the jobs before starting stage 2.