# is it possible to run sbatch in blocking mode?

Tags: stdin, blocking, slurm, sbatch

Is it possible to run sbatch in input blocking mode? I have sbatch called via another controller script. Before going to the next step in the controller script I want to make sure the submitted job is completed and the results of the job are available. What alternatives could be considered? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sbatch` command has the `-W` option. From the [sbatch manpage](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_wait):

> -W, --wait
> Do not exit until the submitted job terminates.

Otherwise, you can use [job dependencies](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_dependency). You can submit a job, and then submit another one with `--dependency=after_ok:<the job id of the first job>` so Slurm will only start the second one after the first one has run properly.

That process can be automated with a workflow management system. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404236/python-cluster-jobs-management) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. -W is what I needed. I do not know how I missed on that :)